# Multiple users for one access_token in web application

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, token

I have a web application without any user login. The web application is used by multiple users and they use the web application to get different kind of data.
The web application consist of 5 buttons at the top and by clicking on these, a ajax request is made to a WebApi that gathers the data from a database and returns it.

I have now implemented token authentication (client_credentail grant for now) in the webapi and I now wonder how the authentication for my web application should work.

For now, each application that should use the API, must provide an client id either to get an access_token. If the client_id is correct, an acess_token is granted, and a refresh_token is created and stored in the database.

My problem is:

If person A vists the web application, a request to the webapi is made with the client_id. An access_token and refresh_token is returned back, and the user can now start use the web application and gather data like before.
But if person B visits the web application, during the time person A is working on the web application, a new token can't be obtained, because the application is already authenticated with an access_token, and either to get a new one, you must use the refresh_token to get a new one. This to prevent a user for obtaining a new token for an application several times.

Sow how can I solve this in a nice standard way? I want the application to be authenticated with an acess_token and used by multiple users.

I have done a diry solution where I have created a long lived access_token and hard coded It in each request, but I know for sure that this is not the right way to do it.